# Switch host from localhost/website to website/ Symfony URL

Tags: symfony, localhost

I'm sorry if this question seems to be stupid...I've just forgot how to do that.

If my main URL is : `http://localhost/Website/web/app_dev.php/`

I would like to access the same page with the URL `Website/`

I remembered it were about hosting so I've just add `127.0.0.1           website` to my hosts file and now I can access with the URL `http://website/Website/web/app_dev.php/`

But I still miss something to get what i want...i just can't remember where I have to go, I think it's not really and directly Symfony related problem. Have you an idea ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you using the builtin web server or something like apache or nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the builtin server (bin/console server:run or start) then you have to specify the port also (http://localhost:8000/Website/web/app_dev.php/)

Answer (score 0):

In fact I figure it out, it was the file httpd_conf from apache i was looking for. It's all fine now. Sorry for your time.